# Problems in using global variables in functions

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, global-variables

I try to use a global variable in my function, see below. I can use the global variable in my func1 to store a value, for Ex. 77, ok. In func2 I try to use the current value that is stored in the global variable but the result is undefined.

Any advice how to get this working?

```
doGet() {
    ...
    var buttonValue;
    ...

func1(e,buttonValue) {
    ...
    buttonValue = size;
    throw buttonValue;
    --> buttonValue ok!
    ...
}

func2(e,buttonValue) {
    ...
    throw buttonValue;
    --> buttonValue undefined!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. The value of global variables cannot be changed in handler functions etc. 
Use [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cacheservice) to store values that have a global scope

Here is a code example:

```
function func1(){
  CacheService.getPrivateCache().put('var_name', 'var_value');
}

function func2(){
  var var_value = CacheService.getPrivateCache().get('var_name');
}
```

Comment: doGet() { ... var cache = CacheService.getPrivateCache(); ... func1(e) { ... cache.put('foo', size); ... ---> ReferenceError:"cache" is not defined. How should CacheService be used? Actually I just try to get a value out of handler function to global scope so any other solution would help me too.

Comment: It does not work in my code: TypeError:Cannot find function put in object CacheService. I also tried to use var CacheService = CacheService.getPrivateCache(); in doGet() but it didnt help. Am I missing some point?

Comment: @Srik this worked for me as well, a nice way to get text input into a kind of Global variable available during the app session.